# How can I find cumulative count within a group using Alibaba PyODPS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, alibaba-cloud

Let us consider I have a data frame named Iris with name, sepallength, sepalwidth, petalwidth and petallength as columns. I want to find the cumulative count of sepallength within a group.

My code:

```
iris['name', 'sepallength', iris.groupby('name').sort('sepallength').sepallength.count()].head(5)
```

But it is showing the wrong result, what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumcount` instead of `count`, the previous one is for window function while the later one is for aggregation.

```
iris['name', 'sepallength', iris.groupby('name').sort('sepallength').sepallength.cumcount()].head(5)
```